# Amazon DynamoDB: Storing integers as Numbers vs. Strings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an application using DynamoDB and I need to be able to store some numbers. At the moment these numbers will only ever be positive integers or occasionally positive numbers with 1 decimal place.

Since DynamoDB has only one Number data type that I assume is somewhat equivalent to a float, is it safe to store integers as Numbers without having to worry about precision causing the returning value to be incorrect (i.e. 1.999999999999 instead of 2)? Or should I save them as strings and parse integers from the strings when I need them. I know that DynamoDB already stores Numbers as strings at some point in the background, but I'm unsure if there is possibility for accuracy loss before that conversion.

As I said, I will only ever be using positive numbers with up to 1 decimal place.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> An attribute of type Number. For example:
>
> "N": "123.45"
>
> Numbers are sent across the network to DynamoDB as strings, to
>   maximize compatibility across languages and libraries. However,
>   DynamoDB treats them as number type attributes for mathematical
>   operations.
>
> **Type: String** Required: No

From the documentation, if you store a number as 1.999999 you will get it as 1.999999.

Also further documentation:

Number

> A Number can have up to 38 digits of precision, and can be positive,
>   negative, or zero.
>
> Positive range: 1E-130 to 9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999E+125
>   Negative range: -9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999E+125 to
>   -1E-130 DynamoDB uses JSON strings to represent Number data in requests and replies. For more information, see DynamoDB Low-Level
>   API.
>
> **If number precision is important, you should pass numbers to DynamoDB
>   using strings that you convert from a number type.**

Comment: That bolded line in the second quote from the docs is exactly what inspired this question, but reading it again I realise I am confusing accuracy and precision. I took the line to mean that numbers may not be stored accurately, when actually it means that if I want to store a number that exceeds the precision limits of their system then it would be better stored as a string. Thank you!

Comment: @GeoffMcLennan Exaclty how I understand it too from the documentations. Since the type of the Numbers are Strings, and the number conversion only happens internally anways there shouldn't be any problems. However always test everything to make sure it works as intended to your setup once you have the setup ready.

Answer (score 9):

Another advantage of storing numbers as **`DynamoDB Number data type`**.

In the `UpdateExpression`, you can use **`+ or -`** to add / subtract the values.

**Example:-**

**Add:-**

```
UpdateExpression : "SET total_val = total_val + :value",            
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {                
            ':value': 2
    },
```

**Subtract:-**

```
UpdateExpression : "SET total_val = total_val - :value",            
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {                
                ':value': 2
        },
```

The above is not possible if you store the number as String data type in DynamoDB.

Comment: This is a good point, but unfortunately does not apply to my specific situation as I will only ever be setting the value manually, not incrementing in any way.

A valid answer though.

Comment: This is not true.  If you store your number as "1000001" you can still do the same mathematical expressions in the update statements.  Perhaps this answer was true in Feb 2017, but it is not now.

Comment: What is the arithmetic precision? Specifically, what happens when you trick dynamodb to perform an update expression like `1e40 + 1`?